# Ломается VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: VS Code постоянно покрывается такими пикселями. При клике в любое место окна это пропадает, потом снова появляется. В чём проблема?]

VS Code постоянно покрывается такими пикселями. При клике в любое место окна это пропадает, потом снова появляется. В чём проблема?

Comment: Жостка. Видеокарта наверно глючит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поискать в настройках драйвера видеокарты дурацкие настройки типа "увеличения резкости" и отключить их. Везде, где можно, выбрать пункт "согласно настройкам приложения".

Answer (score 1):

1. Отключить 'hw acceleration'.
   https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_disable-gpu-acceleration
2. Если неполадка не устранилась, попробовать переустановить программу.
3. Поискать ответы здесь:
   https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93356
   https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93678